# Making large numbers readable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers, long-integer, readability

I'm wondering if there is a way to make large numbers readable in JavaScript. I'm sure there is I just can't find it.
For example, if I am writing

```
for (var i=0; i < 1000000; i++){
codecodecode};
```

is there a way to write that 1000000 so that it's readable without disrupting the for loop?

Furthermore, is there a way of returning a large number so that, too, is readable?

Sorry if I explained this poorly, I'm just starting out...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "readable"?

Comment: perhaps a nearby comment would help. For example, above your loop, you could write `// for i = 0 to 1,000,000` so that you could see what's going on more easily. Other than the answer below, there is no other way to type out numerics

Comment: For formatted output, consider the answers here: [*How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript).

Comment: `10**6` - 10 in the power of 6 = `1000000`

Answer (score 8):

### Add underscore

`100_000_000_000`

`const loopCount = 50_000`

`for (var i=0; i < 1_000_000; i++){
codecodecode};`

for more information go here (https://2ality.com/2018/02/numeric-separators.html)

Comment: This does not work on its own.  The JS Numeric Separator requires adding `@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator` to the list of plugins.

Answer (score 6):

If you are thinking about the *source code*, you can write `1E6`. You are looking for some symbol to seperate the thousands, but unfortunately there is no way.

If you want to convert a number to a more readable string, [then this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```js
    let humanRead = (num,intSep = ',',floatSep = '.') => {

 return new Intl
    .NumberFormat('en-US')
    .format(num)
    .replaceAll('.',floatSep)
    .replaceAll(',',intSep);

}




console.log(humanRead(233234434.23))
    console.log(humanRead(233234434.23,'_'))
    console.log(humanRead(233234434.23,'_','@'))
    console.log(humanRead('') )
    console.log(humanRead('string'))
    console.log(humanRead('st2in9') )
    console.log(humanRead(NaN))
    console.log(humanRead(undefined))
```